# SharePoint CSOM Powershell Reference

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I can't find a good official Microsoft reference anymore for using CSOM with  PowerShell for SharePoint Online.

Working with PowerShell is slightly different then:
JavaScript API reference for SharePoint
REST API reference for SharePoint
.NET server API reference for SharePoint
.NET client API reference for SharePoint

Like here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj162979.aspx

And here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537855(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: From an API perspective, when you use CSOM with PowerShell you're using the .NET libraries. I think what you're looking for is a PowerShell language reference.

Comment: Thanx Derek, enough PowerShell info around, but all CSOM references I found have C# examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are articles about PowerShell in SharePoint online.

Introduction to the SharePoint Online Management Shell.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161388.aspx

Create SharePoint Online sites and add users with Office 365 PowerShell.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt771886.aspx

Manage SharePoint Online users and groups with Office 365 PowerShell.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt771884.aspx

More reference:

Using CSOM in PowerShell scripts with Office 365.

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html